# Issue with textarea rounded corners

Tags: html, css

I have a text area with rounded corners from the top and the bottom, I would like to leave the rounded corners only at the top and remove them from the bottom. How to do that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go.

```css
textarea {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this is weird it doesnt work for me :(

Comment: Which browser are you using? and can you share the code within http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: im using chrome, firefox, opera, safari .. all browsers, i think my code will not be suitable as im using laravel framework

Comment: If the demo above works then you'll have to work it out whatever causes it not to work with your set up.

Comment: you are right, i will try again

Comment: Your solution worked, I had a file that conflict with my customized CSS. thank you brother